If the diagonals of a quadrilateral $ABCD$ meet at $O$, then prove that $\triangle ABC: \triangle ADC =BO:OD$
This question is from the book Challenge and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics.
This is what I have tried:
Let us assume that the foot of altitude DX of triangle $\triangle ADC$ lies on $AO$ (not on $AO$ extended) and the foot of altitude $BY$ of triangle $\triangle ABC$ lies on $OB$ (not on $OB$ extended), now we know that the triangles $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle ABC$ are on the same base $AC$ thus $$\dfrac{\triangle ABC}{\triangle ADC} = \dfrac{BY}{DX}.$$ Now $\triangle DOX$ and  $\triangle BOY$ are similar because $\angle XOY$ and $\angle BOY$ are vertically opposite hence,
$$\dfrac{\triangle ABC}{\triangle ADC } = \dfrac{BY}{DX} = \dfrac{BO}{DO}.$$
But if $\angle XOY$ and $\angle BOY$ are not vertically opposite, then how will I prove $\triangle DOX$ and  $\triangle BOY$ are similar also? Please let me know if there are any errors in the proof.

I think there is a typo in your proof, but also it seems your main problem is that $X,Y$ are not the same point. But... you can make them the same point: draw the perpendicular to $AC$ from $B$, draw the parallel to $AC$ at $D$, where those meet erect a new triangle $AD'C$ with the same area as $ADC$, and your proof will work.

I first took the hights $BP$ of $\triangle ABC$ and $DQ$ of $\triangle ADC$(to the base $AC$), and continued them to an infinite line, and took two more perpendiculars of $BP$ from $B$ and of $DQ$ from $D$,wich meet the line $DQ$ at $P$, and the line $BP$ at $F$, and so in the end we have a rectangle $GBFD$.  
As $DF||PQ||BG$, then $\frac{BP}{DQ}=\frac{BO}{DO}$ by the similarity of $\triangle BPO$ to $\triangle DQO $. As  $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADC$ share the same base $AC$, then
$\frac{A_{\triangle ABC}}{A_{\triangle ADC}}=\frac{BP}{DQ}$. 
Therfore, $\frac{A_{\triangle ABC}}{A_{\triangle ADC}}=\frac{BO}{DO}$ 
($A_{\triangle ABC}$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$ )

